Fit of a (discrete) Pareto distribution for prices of goods
I have goods in a price range from 200 up to a few 10 Mio. I have price bins
$$ P_1 = [200,500[, \quad P_2 = [500, 3000[, \quad P_3 = [3000, \infty[ $$
I would restrict the latter interval to something like $[3000, 3 \, \text{Millions} [$.
For each bin $P$ I know number of pieces $N_P$ and a revenue $R_P$.
Assuming a (discrete) Pareto distribution
$$ f_\alpha(x) = \frac{\alpha \, x_\text{min}^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} $$
this translates into
$$ N_P = c \cdot \sum_{x \in P} f_\alpha(x) $$
$$ R_P = c \cdot \sum_{x \in P} x \, f_\alpha(x) $$
Typical values for $N_P$ are in the range of a few Millions.
Based on this information I would like to estimate the shape parameter $\alpha$, that means I need to fit the function $f_\alpha(x)$ w.r.t. to the six values $N_{P_1}, R_{P_1} \ldots N_{P_3}, R_{P_3}$.
Questions

Is a Pareto distribution the right way to go, or are there preferred
distributions for the problem?
What would be a reasonable function
$C(N_{P_k}, R_{P_k})$ I should minimize in the fit?
What are reasonable discrete support points $x \in P_k$ I should use? Given the three bins and six know values, how many support points $x$ should I
use? And how shall they be distributed? (I guess somehow
logarithmically)

(Curve fitting itself is not an issue)
